# Get list of names from site while web-scraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to get list of names from [site.](https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index)
I make such code:

```
library("rvest") 
library("magrittr")

url <- 'https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index'
read_html(url) %>% 
        html_nodes(".name")%>% 
             html_children()
```

and I got:

```
 [1] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/vankorskoe">Ванкорское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\ ...
 [2] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/russkoe">Русское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\n      ...
 [3] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/lyantorskoe">Лянторское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small> ...
 [4] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/urnenskoye">Урненское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\n ...
 [5] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/usinskoe">Усинское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\n    ...
 [6] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/kamennoe-west">Каменное месторождение (западная часть)</a>\n                       ...
 [7] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/sovetskoe">Советское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\n  ...
 [8] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/priobskoe-south">Приобское месторождение (южная лицензионная территория (ЮЛТ))</a> ...
 [9] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/zapadno-surgutskoe">Западно-Сургутское месторождение</a>\n                         ...
[10] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/north-komsomolskoe">Северо-Комсомольское месторождение</a>\n                       ...
[11] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/verkhnechonskoye">Верхнечонское месторождение</a>\n                            <br ...
[12] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/prirazlomnoye-rosneft">Приразломное месторождение (Роснефть)</a>\n                 ...
[13] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/fyodorovskoe">Фёдоровское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><smal ...
[14] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/srednebotuobinskoe">Среднеботуобинское месторождение</a>\n                         ...
[15] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/rogozhnikovskoe">Рогожниковское месторождение</a>\n                            <br ...
[16] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/yaregskoye">Ярегское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\n  ...
[17] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/kumkolskoe">Кумкольское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small> ...
[18] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/filanovskogo">Месторождение им. В. Филановского</a>\n                            < ...
[19] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/sugmutskoe">Сугмутское месторождение</a>\n                            <br><small>\ ...
[20] <div class="name">\n            <a href="/en/oil-gas-field/meretoyahinskoe">Меретояхинское месторождение</a>\n                            <br ...
```

I want to get all from data after `<a href="/en/oil-gas-field/....">`

```
Ванкорское месторождение
Русское месторождение...
```

and so on.
When I tried to put

```
read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes(".name")%>% 
         html_children() %>% 
            html_attr("/en/oil-gas-field/")
```

I have got:

```
    [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[49] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What function should I use?
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I searched answers in other question and didn't find

Comment: I mean you have asked questions before but don't seem to have accepted any given answers. You don't have to but it is helpful.

Comment: Please do not use web tag. It is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the direct child `a` of the parent with class `name`. You can use css [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) for this

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

titles <- read_html('https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index') %>%
          html_nodes('.name > a') %>%
          html_text()
```

Comment: That is kind. I meant more generally as a courtesy to those who have answered your prior questions. It is just learning how the site works :-)